# Storing 1010 in a matrix with Java or C

Tags: java, c, matrix

I had been asked this question in an interview(which i could not crack). I was still keen on knowing how to solve this.

I had to design a chess board like structure where i had to store 1 instead of the black area and 0 instead of the white area upto 4 rows and columns. The program could be solved either in C or java. I know it has to be a simple answer.

Could anyone help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. (copied from flag dialog)

Comment: umm... just create an array and fill it with indexes? The algorithm is not too hard. Where are you stuck implementing it?

Comment: Are you asking us how to fill a multidimensional arrays with alternating 1's and 0's? And this was asked in an interview?!

Comment: @Kon Perhaps there was a rule on how to implement it that was not discussed in the question, because I'm appalled of how easy this sounds and that it was asked in an interview...

Comment: Probably a [FizzBuzz](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html) type of test -- not very hard, yet weeds out a lot of candidates.

Comment: You dont even need a matrix, you could use a 16-bit short value.

Comment: @gparyani.. thanks for commenting.. well as i mentioned as I was not able to answer this question in the interview hence wasnt selected and I am just asking it here for my general information which might prove useful for me in the future.  You probably find it easy because you might be experienced in Java and coding. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is not too difficult, even for arbitrarily sized arrays:

First, allocate a 2D array of the appropriate size. In some languages, you need to allocate each row manually. Both Java and C can do that for you. Java: `int[][] board = new int[w][h]`

Then, for each row, for each column, compute if the cell should be black or white:

- Add both indexes together, and take that value mod-2: `(x+y)%2`.
- Taking modulo-2 (parity) is equivalent to taking the lowest bit: `(x+y)&1`.
- Perhaps this is easier to understand, and does the same: `x%2 ^ y%2` or `x&1 ^ y&1` where `^` denotes bitwise XOR.
- Or, you could XOR first, then take the lowest bit: `(x^y)%2` or `(x^y)&1`.
- On the other hand, sum of parities will not work because then you'd have `2` on odd-odd positions.

Both languages (as well as every other c-like language) support the classic for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

`i = 0` happens before the loop, and is the best place to declare the iteration variable. `i < size` is computed before each iteration, and if it's falsy (`0` in C, `false` in Java), iteration stops. `i++` is computed after each iteration.

Most languages store the array size with the array. In C/C++, you have to store the array size separately or use a smart array like [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You also have to be careful not to access outside the array (Java throws an exception, but C/C++ lets you write into random pieces of memory - [a great way to cause a remote program to misbehave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/buffer_overflow)).

C doesn't let you declare an array whose size is not known at compile time. If you want this, you need either a pointer to an array of pointers (`int**` - don't forget to de/allocate each row), or to flatten the array (`int*` - more memory efficient, but you need to do `board[x + w*y]` to access the cells).

Of course, if the size *is* known at compile time and small enough, you can just use an array literal and be done with it; `int[][] board = new int[][]{{0,1,0,1}, {1,0,1,0}, {0,1,0,1}, {1,0,1,0}}`

---

Java (parts left out are an excercise for the reader):

```
int[][] board = new int[h][w];
for(int x ...){
  for(int y ...){
    board[y][x] = (x+y)%2;
  }
}
```

For comparison, here's Ruby:

```
board = Array.new(h) {|y|
  Array.new(w) {|x|
    (x+y)%2
  }
}
#or (this time inlined)
board = (0...h).map{|x| (0...w).map{|y| (x+y)%2 }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your genuine help without any criticism. It shall definitely prove useful for me

Answer (score -1):

You can use a *bit-array* and store the 4x4 board in a single integer.

```
bin    hex
1010    A
0101    5
1010    A
0101    5
```

=>

```
int board = 0xA5A5;
```

You can set the value in a cell, designated by 2 indicies, `i` [0..3] and `j` [0..3], with:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
board |= (1 << (i*4+j));
```

Or clear the value in a cell with:

```
board &= ~(1 << (i*4+j));
```

And you can discover the value in a cell with:

```
printf("cell at (%d,%d) has value %d\n", i, j, (board >> (i*4)+j) & 1);
```

To fill a blank "structure" with the desired pattern,

```
board = 0;
for (i=0; i < 4; i++)
    for (j=0; j < 4; j++)
        if (!((i+j)%2))
            board |= (1 << (i*4+j));
```

SCCCE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i,j,board;

    for (i=0; i < 4; i++)
        for (j=0; j < 4; j++)
            if ((i+j)%2)
                board &= ~(1 << (i*4+j));
            else
                board |= (1 << (i*4+j));

    for (i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j=0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d ", (board >> (i*4+j)) & 1);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```